# After Javascript confirm dialog, web page goes to top. How to stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a confirm dialog as a yes/no confirmation on whether to remove a few elements from the page. That part works fine. The problem is that after clicking either 'confirm' or 'cancel' the page scrolls to the top. How can I stop this behavior?

```
$('.deleter').click(function () {
    if (confirm('Do you want to remove' + $(this).attr('name') + '. This action can not be undone.')) {
        $('.g' + $(this).attr('itemId')).remove();
        $('.' + $(this).attr('itemId')).remove();
    }
});
```

Failing that, a work around that sets the window back to it's previous space would be fine.

edit: HTML CODE

```
<a href='#' class='deleter' name='eg' itemId='4'>delete</a>
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: I think This may be due to `<a href="#">`

Comment: is this ".deleter" class inside an anchor tag ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually jumping to the location `#` (the default behaviour of `a`).
You need to prevent this default behaviour by `preventDefault()`.

Try this,

```
$('.deleter').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Do you want to remove' + $(this).attr('name') + '. This action can not be undone.')) {
        $('.g' + $(this).attr('itemId')).remove();
        $('.' + $(this).attr('itemId')).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: If you have JS in your `onclick=''` attribute, tack `return false;` onto the end to prevent this behavior: `<a href='#' onclick='yourFunc(); return false;'>my link</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Anil is correct. Your link is telling it to go to the top of the page:

```
<a href='#' class='deleter' name='eg' itemId='4'>delete</a>
```

If you don't want your link to act like an actual anchor link then either:

a. don't make it a link. Bind the click event to a different type of object (such as a button)

or

b. give the href a proper null value such as javascript:

```
 <a href='javascript:;' class='deleter' name='eg' itemId='4'>delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're binding the event to an anchor element, whose default behavior is to cause a GET to a resource. The following will prevent the default behavior of the anchor:

```
$('.deleter').click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    if (confirm('Do you want to remove' + $(this).attr('name') + '. This action can not be undone.')){
    $('.g' + $(this).attr('itemId')).remove();  
    $('.' + $(this).attr('itemId')).remove();
    } 
});
```

**Or:**

```
$('.deleter').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (confirm('Do you want to remove' + $(this).attr('name') + '. This action can not be undone.')){
    $('.g' + $(this).attr('itemId')).remove();  
    $('.' + $(this).attr('itemId')).remove();
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because of the anchor tag. change the anchor tag like this change ** href="#_" **

```
<a href='#_' class='deleter' name='eg' itemId='4'>delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirm, Alert and Prompt are browser dependant functionalities actually. We cant change its behaviour or design. Or else you want to use jquery plugins for dialogs rather than these. Refer this, http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/